# Estimating the probability of an event using the logistic function in R

Tags: r, logistic, glmnet

I need some help to estimate the probability of bankruptcy, using the lags of several explanatory variables. I want to use historical data and estimate the parameters using a logit/probit model, and then use them to calculate the probability of bankruptcy of the active firms. I have more than 50 explanatory variables, so I think I need to use a Lasso type technique. My main problem is that I don't know how to specify the model in lags. Any help how to set up the model and estimation is greatly appreciated. Here is a sample data set:

```
df <- structure(list(Firm_id = c(10000567L, 10000567L, 10000567L, 10000567L, 
                                 10000222L, 10000222L, 
                                 10000123L, 10000123L, 10000123L, 10000123L, 10000123L, 10000123L)
                      , Date = c("12-12-2019", "12-12-2018", "12-12-2017", "12-12-2016",
                                 "12-12-2021", "12-12-2020", 
                                 "12-12-2022", "12-12-2021", "12-12-2020", "12-12-2019", "12-12-2018", "12-12-2017")
                     , Bankrupt = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                     , X1 = c(1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 4, 3, 7, 5, 3, 5, 2)
                     , X2 = c(2, 3, 1, 7, 4, 5, 2, 9, 3, 2, 2, 1)
                     , X3 = c(6, 3, 9, 11, 14, 15, 12, 32, 22, 14, 23, 11)
                     , X4 = c(15, 1, 12, 11, 11, 5, 8, 4, 9, 13, 15, 12)
                     , X5 = c(21, 35, 31, 71, 34, 65, 72, 29, 93, 22, 12, 31)
                     , X6 = c(7, 6, 5, 2, 1, 1, 8, 1, 7, 4, 6, 1))
                 , class = "data.frame"
                 , row.names = c(NA, -12L)
) 

glmnet(df[,4:9], df$Bankrupt, family = "binomial", alpha = 1, lambda = NULL)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on what exactly is the problem?

Comment: My main problem is that I don't know how to specify the model. I used the glmnet command to estimate the model (not in lags), but got the following warning: Warning message:
In lognet(xd, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  :
  one multinomial or binomial class has fewer than 8  observations; dangerous ground

Comment: Why do you feel you have to run a LASSO model? // A difficulty I’ve found when I’ve worked on bankruptcy prediction is that impending bankruptcy tends to be detected and remedied, meaning that people/firms can be on thin ice yet get out of it with proper interventions. The bankruptcy probability is technically working properly by noticing these remedies but might not be the exact value of interest to the economic context.

Comment: It is just a warning that warns you that you have very little data and could get rubbish results because of this.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why the duration how long the firm does business pose a problem? Are you actully considering time series data? Or repeated measurements?

Comment: @Dave, I have 50+ explanatory variables and it would be useful to automatically select a subset of relevant features from these variables, and I think for my case I need a model with very few parameters that I can easily explain and visualize.

Comment: @cdalitz, I want to control for the time as well as other features. For instance, in 2008 the economic situation was exceptionally bad and many firms have gone bust. How would you specify and estimate such a model?

Comment: @Dave That's correct, I included all those useful comments in the description, but didn't know how, so I posted a new question here and deleted the previous one. Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: Please take a few minutes to view our [help] so you can make best use of this site.