# How to estimate the probability of a binary event using lags of independent variables

Tags: r, logistic, glmnet

My apologies if this is a trivial question. I need some help to estimate the probability of bankruptcy, using the lags of several explanatory variables. I want to use historical data and estimate the parameters using a logit/probit model, and then use them to calculate the probability of bankruptcy of the active firms. I have more than 50 explanatory variables, so I think I need to use a Lasso type technique. My main problem is that I don't know how to specify the model in lags. Any help how to set up the model and estimation is greatly appreciated. Here is a sample data set:

```
df <- structure(list(Firm_id = c(10000567L, 10000567L, 10000567L, 10000567L, 
                                 10000222L, 10000222L, 
                                 10000123L, 10000123L, 10000123L, 10000123L, 10000123L, 10000123L)
                      , Date = c("12-12-2019", "12-12-2018", "12-12-2017", "12-12-2016",
                                 "12-12-2021", "12-12-2020", 
                                 "12-12-2022", "12-12-2021", "12-12-2020", "12-12-2019", "12-12-2018", "12-12-2017")
                     , Bankrupt = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                     , X1 = c(1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 4, 3, 7, 5, 3, 5, 2)
                     , X2 = c(2, 3, 1, 7, 4, 5, 2, 9, 3, 2, 2, 1)
                     , X3 = c(6, 3, 9, 11, 14, 15, 12, 32, 22, 14, 23, 11)
                     , X4 = c(15, 1, 12, 11, 11, 5, 8, 4, 9, 13, 15, 12)
                     , X5 = c(21, 35, 31, 71, 34, 65, 72, 29, 93, 22, 12, 31)
                     , X6 = c(7, 6, 5, 2, 1, 1, 8, 1, 7, 4, 6, 1))
                 , class = "data.frame"
                 , row.names = c(NA, -12L)
) 

glmnet(df[,4:9], df$Bankrupt, family = "binomial", alpha = 1, lambda = NULL)
```

Comment: You [posted](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/619985/247274) this a few minutes ago and deleted it after getting insightful comments, only to post again but now without the comments. Could you please explain why?